# Should model also serve as a repository?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, coding-style, standards

I wonder if it's correct to use model as a repository. Reason is that it would be much simpler and would make much more sense in certain scenarios. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do things so maybe someone can point out if I'm going the right direction.

#### Example

You have `Account`, every `Account` would have `Sessions` and `Projects`. Now wouldn't it be much more sensible to do something like `acc.AddProject("new project")` and `acc.DeleteProjectById(3)` instead of pulling repositories in controller and wasting codespace?

This is what I have so far, I wonder if I'm going to right direction here.

```
public class Account
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Project> Projects
    {
        get
        {
            var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.Bootstrapper.Kernel;
            var projectRepository = kernel.Get<IProjectRepository>();

            return projectRepository.GetByAccountId(Id);
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<AccountSession> Sessions
    {
        get
        {
            var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.Bootstrapper.Kernel;
            var sessionRepository = kernel.Get<IAccountSessionRepository>();

            return sessionRepository.GetByAccountId(Id);
        }
    }

    public Project AddProject(string name, string description)
    {
        var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.Bootstrapper.Kernel;
        var projectRepository = kernel.Get<IProjectRepository>();

        return projectRepository.Add(name, description, Id.ToString());
    }

    public AccountSession AddSession(string ip, string hash, string salt)
    {
        var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.Bootstrapper.Kernel;
        var sessionRepository = kernel.Get<AccountSessionRepository>();

        return sessionRepository.Add(Id.ToString(), ip, hash, salt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about seems to be a mix of two approaches.

Firstly, having those sorts of methods on a model is akin to the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). This pattern basically means that each object has `CRUD` operations.

However it also sounds like you want a design that evolves from [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), whereby the objects themselves contain all of their required logic (as opposed to a hexagonal structure with "Service" classes).

DDD does not state that persistence is part of the model - but the logic is. You would still leave persistence in a dedicated repository, but all of your logic would sit in your models. Then your repositories just update the models as is. The idea there is that your code becomes much more expressive as to the inner workings of your domain (which is what you're going for with your code example).

Answer (score 1):

I typically don't. I like to keep my services separate from the DTOs they pass around. It's mostly personal preference to reduce coupling.

What if you want to override the methods? You're now extending an DTO instead of a service, resulting in a new DTO. It's too much coupling in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. This doesn't sound like DDD. Let me point out few things why it isn't.

- The model should be designed loosely coupled with other layers in the application, meaning no dependencies on the layers on either side of domain layer (i.e. database and facade layers).
- The domain model should focus on a specific business operational domain. Doesn't mean it will have to do the operation itself.
- Model should be isolated from other layers in the application architecture.
- Suppose I need to instantiate the the model object to serialize to json/xml and serialization process is being done by some other repository object I'm that case it wouldn't make sense to instantiate the model+repository of that domain.
- It should be an abstract and cleanly separated layer enabling easier maintenance, testing, and versioning.